# Add details to Keras Model File or juste .h5 file

Tags: python, keras, win32com, h5py

I would like to know if it's possible to change the description of a model file :
[image]

I want to add a line saying "This model predicts [my targets]". My model is an .h5 file.

I found a function where i can get the metadata/details of a file :

```
import win32com.client # pip install pypiwin32
metadata = ['Name', 'Size', 'Item type', 'Date modified', 'Date created', 'Date accessed', 'Attributes', 'Offline status', 'Availability', 'Perceived type', 'Owner', 'Kind', 'Date taken', 'Contributing artists', 'Album', 'Year', 'Genre', 'Conductors', 'Tags', 'Rating', 'Authors', 'Title', 'Subject', 'Categories', 'Comments', 'Copyright', '#', 'Length', 'Bit rate', 'Protected', 'Camera model', 'Dimensions', 'Camera maker', 'Company', 'File description', 'Masters keywords', 'Masters keywords']
    
def get_file_metadata(path, filename, metadata):
    # Path shouldn't end with backslash, i.e. "E:\Images\Paris"
    # filename must include extension, i.e. "PID manual.pdf"
    # Returns dictionary containing all file metadata.
    sh = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Shell.Application', 0)
    ns = sh.NameSpace(path)

    # Enumeration is necessary because ns.GetDetailsOf only accepts an integer as 2nd argument
    file_metadata = dict()
    item = ns.ParseName(str(filename))
    for ind, attribute in enumerate(metadata):
        attr_value = ns.GetDetailsOf(item, ind)
        if attr_value:
            file_metadata[attribute] = attr_value

    return file_metadata
```

But the function `SetDetailsOf` doesn't exist. So, i do not know  how to do it.

Comment: The metadata you are getting are OS/file system tags, **not** HDF5 attributes. As such, you can't use `h5py` to modify or add them. You need to use `win32com`. I updated the tags to reflect this.